# Cloning a PHP PDO recordset object to count the rows returned by a select statement

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm refactoring part of a PHP application which uses adodb as db library, in order to start using PDO.

I need something which provides me the number of rows included in a select recordset, something that can easily replace the old `$rs->RecordCount()` adodb method that I used before. It should work for sqlite3.

I can't simply re-execute the query (or re-execute the query using a `select count(*)` ) because I can't change so much the original application, the application calls in many parts a function `get_num_rows($rs)` (which contains just `$rs->RecordCount()` ) and I can just change the content of that function.

I tried cloning the recordset object and counting the records fetched:

```
function get_num_rows($rs)
{
    $rs_copy = clone $rs;
    return (count($rs_copy->fetchAll()));
}
```

but it doesn't work, because `$rs_copy->fetchAll()` returns me `false`. I can't do it on the original recordset because later in the applicaiton I need to fetch it again and I think there is no way in PDO sqlite to reuse the recordset (correct me if I'm wrong).

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to get? Count of all rows in order to implement pagination or the count of returned rows?

Comment: @nikic: `$result -> rowCount ()` works for updates only.

Comment: Please try this for cloning

    $rs_copy = unserialize(serialize($rs));

Comment: @Gaurav: PDO objects cannot be serialized.

Comment: **You don't need no row count nor another fetch later in application**. Just fetch it at once into array and then use count() function. If you can't change surrounding code, you'd better leave current ADODB alone

Comment: As I told, the application fetches again later, I can't change it because otherwise I should change a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` run as a second query is the recommended way to count the number of rows in a result set when using `LIMIT` in your primary query. It won't fetch the same data twice, it simply counts how many rows are found and returns 1 row, an integer.  Another way to find the number of rows when using the `LIMIT` statement is to use `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (field list) FROM ...` in your first query, then run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to get the number of rows, however, this method is slower than the previous one mentioned.  Be aware that running `count()` in PHP will only give you the number of rows returned, not the actual number of rows found in the database (if you're using `LIMIT`).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possibility is to do like col shrapnel suggested and store the result in an array. You might be able to keep the interface clean by extending PDOStatement and then

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS

So it will return you EugenioEnhancedPDOStatement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I have found an easier, quick and dirty solution, my new `get_num_rows()` will be something like:

```
$temp_ar = explode("FROM", $rs->queryString);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$temp_ar[1];

$conn->query($sql);

...
```

Comment: use the third arg to explode() so it only splits once.

Answer (score -1):

You can't properly clone and/or serialize/unserialize PDO objects, most probably because they are tightly tied to a connection resource.

The fact is, there is no point cloning it. If `$rs` is a PDOStatement object, you can just re-execute it, since you have access to it. This is one of the main advantage of prepared statements, **prepare once, execute multiple times**.

Like this:

```
function get_num_rows($rs)
{
 $rs->execute();
 return (count($rs->fetchAll()));
}
```

You guessed it: calling execute() **on the same PDOStatement instance the second time without specifying any parameters** will **reuse the last set of parameters and re-execute the statement as is.**

Therefore, there is no need to clone PDOStatement objects.

Comment: This perverted task (to fetch the same data twice just to count it) is not, for sure, what PDO invented for.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I agree that it isn't, and I never said that it was. I'm answering OP's question. Sure it isn't optimal: but I'm not going to rewrite all his code for him. If you have a better demonstrable solution to this problem, I'd like to see it in an answer. I may even vote you up for it. :)

Comment: I never come up with a solution for the problem I see no sense in

Comment: I don't understand why you don't see sense on this, I just have to get the number of rows in a function without touching all the rest of the code.